# OpenDaylight topology showing multiple openvswitches when I connect hosts to virtual bridge in openVswitch

Tags: sdn, opendaylight, openflow

I installed openVswitch on one ubuntu physical machine, ODL on another physical machine. I can see the the topology in ODL, showing only one switch which is fine. Now when I connect another host to the openVswitch installed machine by mapping the interface to the virtual br in switch, by using ovs-vsctl add-port my-br eth0, now ODL topology is showing another switch connected with host. But there is only one openVswitch.

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the GUI when you are looking at the topology? dlux?

it's possible there is a bug in the GUI, but that feature is not really
maintained or supported any more.

can you check what you get from a GET request to the operational topology?
something like this:

```
curl -u admin:admin https://${ODL IP}:8181/restconf/operational/network-topology:network-topology
```

how many "nodes" do you have? Also, the nodes will have an id associated with
them which is the decimal equivalent of the mac address for that device. That
might help figure out what you are looking at.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to GUI. I have 2 nodes connected to two different openvSwitches installed ubunty machines. when I map the interface to the vr br's respectively, I see 3 switches but it is only two.

I shall try what you suggested.